Can this dragon fly with a rider?
In my world, dragon-like creatures were engineered by an advanced civilization, designed both as living weapons and curiosities. Unlike traditional methods of genetic modification, these dragons were created from scratch, giving them a biology that is vastly different and alien compared to other life forms.
Skeletal Structure and Limbs:
Their bones are composed of interwoven hollow structures made from a carbon polymer fiber, which are filled with a compressed, lighter-than-air gas. This combination makes their structure strong, lightweight, and slightly flexible. Although their skeletal framework mirrors the general shape of tetrapods, these dragons possess six limbs instead of four. Just behind their front legs, a pair of long wings emerges, positioned slightly toward the abdomen.
Their wings are supported by a bone similar to the furcula found in birds, which anchors the strong muscles necessary for flight. This configuration gives them a stocky, somewhat chubby appearance. Their legs are sleek and bird-like, designed to maximize speed without adding unnecessary weight.
Mobility and Flight:
They walk and run on hooved "knuckles." This allows them to protect their elongated digits during running, while still being able to use these fingers for tasks like carrying objects. The hooves also aid in gaining the momentum necessary for takeoff, as they run to initiate flight.
External Features:
The dragons' bodies are covered in a unique blend of keratin-based feather-scales, embedded with deposits of iron sulfide. (I initially considered that their scales could contain deposits of whatever metals they ingest, but I remain concerned about the added weight such structures would create.) Their tail is short, with long scales reminiscent of a swallow’s tail or a shortened, closed version of a peacock’s plume.
Fire-Breathing Mechanism:
One of their most formidable abilities is their fire-breathing mechanism. These dragons can expel a pressurized gas mixture composed primarily of metallic compounds, especially silver. When released, the gas is ignited by a specialized organ located at the front of their mouths. This organ generates high voltage, producing a brief instant of plasma. The result is a thermite or Greek fire-like substance that burns at extreme temperatures and is exceptionally difficult to extinguish.
Energy and Metabolism:
These creatures possess a little fantasy touch, because they have an organ that functions akin to a perpetual motion device, capable of generating infinite energy. Because of this, they do not need lungs, and their digestive systems are highly simplified. They consume only small amounts of food to replace lost matter, as their bodies are able to synthesize most of the lipids, and sugars they need to survive.
Due to their energy system, I thought they would require a specialized cooling mechanism. So they have two heart-like pumping organs located at the base of their wings, which circulate a cooling liquid throughout their bodies. When the liquid heats up, it is redirected to their wings and long, specialized scales, which function as radiators, dissipating excess heat.
Behavior and Bonding:
While aggressive and highly territorial, these dragons exhibit a docile temperament toward certain individuals who possess specific genetic markers. These markers link these individuals to the ancient owners of the dragon’s ancestors. How this recognition works I still don’t know, maybe they detect certain pheromones produced by people with these genes, or perhaps they require contact with blood to sample the DNA and then recognize by memory their owners.
Obviously, in my setting there are dragon riders, but probably only children, women, or short/ slim people in general.
Setting aside the fantastical element of their perpetual motion organ, do you think the rest of their biology is plausible? Mainly their ability to fly while carrying a rider and the mechanics of their thermite-like fire-breathing. I chose thermite because it seemed like the most destructive fire reaction that a living organism could theoretically generate and somewhat control.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello @Vevol, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. That comment by the automated Community BOT is a red flag indicating your question has failed to pass the basic definition of a good question on Stack Exchange. The service is meant to be used to help people find solutions to specific problems. "Review my Idea" questions are a difficult fit here because they don't follow SE's basic model of one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Worse, our goal is to help you build an imaginary world. ... (*Continued*)

... Making fictional things factual isn't our sweet spot. Please take the time to read the [tour] and [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand us. It might also help to search our Stack - we've answered a lot of questions about dragons. Thanks.

@JBH In my opinion, this is a valid question, with answers being ways in which the system is impossible or inaccurate.

@WhatsYourIQ192 No question asking if an idea is plausible, feasible, realistic, etc., is valid because the worldbuilding is already done. The only alternative is the [tag:internal-consistency] tag, which has specific rules. However, even that tag doesn't ask if someting is plausible, feasible, realsitic, etc. It's purpose is to test the viability of of a worldbuilding rule. So, no, not really.

@JBH What really makes a question answerable is not following the rules. I have a question that was closed, but before it was closed, someone made an answer. What does prevent people from answering questions is the question being closed. Who are we supposed to ask if the Q&A site won’t let you use Q&A? Some other company? I bet stack exchange doesn’t like you diverting their traffic to other sites just because of your stupid rules. And what are they even for? Nothing!

@WhatsYourIQ192 The definition of "Q&A site" for Stack Exchange is found in the [help] and nowhere else. Please don't hijack other user's comment trees with concerns about how Stack Exchange operates. Please open a question in [meta].

Good point. But still, it is a question & answer site, not a question & argument site.

Your main problem is size.
Assuming your world has Earth-like gravity, the max probable size and mass of a dragon would be about that of Quetzalcoatlus northropi, the biggest possible flying creature that could take off from the ground. It was about 12 meters in wingspan, and weighted up to 250kg, so really, really light for its size.
You cannot go much bigger than that, without using some more fancy mechanism than buoyant gas in the bones. All the gas would barely be enough to give them (maybe) extra 80 kg lift. Sure, maybe you can give your dragon a gas-sack with much bigger volume and buoyancy, but this would be silly, your dragon would have to look like a blimp to make any sense at all, as with size, mass increases much faster than buoyancy increases with volume.
So lets be generous, and make your dragon 15 meter in wingspan, and 300 kg in mass, at the absolute top. Fill their bones with as much gas as possible without messing up their skeleton into a bloated mess. Flying creatures can lift up to about 25% of their total mass if they push it. That should maybe give you enough extra lift to take a rider up to 80-ish kilograms (with extreme difficulty), or a rider of about 60-70kg more easily.
Now, HOW to ride a dragon? Most fiction depicts people literally riding a dragon like a mount, atop of its back or neck. But this makes very little sense. Putting extra mass above the wing-level would strain the animal, and putting the rider in front of the dragon's center of mass would make the dragon pitch down all the time, and waste energy counteracting it.
The most optimal way for one to ride the dragon, is to mimic what birds of prey do: have the dragon carry the rider in its talons, under the belly. This balances the dragon nicely, putting the weight of the rider snugly against the lift forces of the wings. It also allows the rider to actually see what is under their dragon, not just above it. Essentially, the dragon acts like a wing-propelled hang-glider.
There are many extra benefits of doing it  that way. if the rider is in a harness underneath the dragon, they can use a system of pulleys and ropes to not just control the dragon with far greater precision than the "saddle and reins" configuration, but also counteract the dragon's pitch, roll and yaw somewhat so that the flight is not a vomit-inducing adventure in extreme vertigo for the rider.
The dragon above would also provide some extra shade against the sun's glare, and to a lesser degree, against windblast (sitting atop a back of a dragon would be a surefire way to have your face whiplashed off with air drag whenever it dove down).
Finally, the bottom-harness configuration would let the rider get off their dragon without the need to land. They could just make the dragon glide low to the ground, unclip their harness and jog for a few steps to lose velocity, and the dragon can just keep gliding to its roost, or to do something else, without forcing it to land every time the rider wants to touch the ground. Picking up a rider could work in reverse: you stand on an open field with your harness clip up, the dragon glides right above your head and clips you in. Imagine something between getting into a ski-lift and being caught and picked up by a giant (but gentle) hawk.
Really, if the dragons have perpetual energy sources, need very little food, and are used primarily for riding, then its more efficient to just let them keep soaring on high winds like an albatross 24/7, and only call them down when necessary. Only have them land for occasional feeding, vet checks and maintenance, otherwise its annoying for the animal to land, and a waste of time/energy to do so.

One additional idea could be to tie the needed cooling of the body (if the perpetual energy core is prone to overheating) to the need to fly and stay airborne more or less the whole time (you can scale that as wanted) so the wind blowing can be used for cooling. Nice essay and ideas (+1).

Good answer, but I'll quibble with the lighter-than-air gas in bones. The absolute limit for lift at room temp/sea level is 1.2kg per cubic meter, assuming a zero-mass bubble of hard vacuum. A cubic meter is a LOT of bone. The difference between bird-style bones filled with regular air and dragon-bones filled with the best possible LTA gas is grams at the scales you're discussing. Skip the lighter-than-air aspect or make it magical anti-gravity, because it only undermines the physics otherwise.

Just noting that while resticting one's weight for work sucks, the weights suggested in this answer are apparently quite feasible in a professional setting: https://cantercraze.com/how-much-do-jockeys-weigh/

@JayMcEh So, just hollow structures filled to the brim with ol' atmospheric gas?

@Vevol Pneumatized bird bones are more spongy than hollow like straws. The larger bones are actively involved in their respiration, not just sealed off.  Obviously your dragons can be built however you want, and their bones (and any gases therein) can provide any lift you desire... they just won't be doing so via atmospheric buoyancy. It requires some form of magi-science.

@JayMcEh. Yeah, thinking about it again, you are right. Even if the bones were perfectly hollow, and as thick as possible for a flying animal , it would hardly make a difference. Also pointless, IRL giant pterosaurs managed to fly perfectly well without it.
